Closed Datalist does not reopen in Edge
In Microsoft Edge, using a Work Profile, it shows an "X" to close a datalist from a text input field.
Once i click to close it, there is no way to make it reappear.

In Google Chrome and in Microsoft Edge using a Personal profile, that "X" button does not exist.
The problem is that all users here are using a Work Profile (as it should be) and some of them clicked the option to close the dataList and now they cannot use that field as we do not know how to make it return.
What may we try to make the list show again?
We did try private mode, reloading the page, clearing the site storage in the developer tools (F12) and nothing of these solved the issue.
Using Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.56
This is the code for the input, if it is usefull (as I think the issue is Edge, not the html):
<div class="form-floating">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CompanySelect" list="companyDataList" />                                            
   <label for="CompanySelect" data-translate-text="Supplier"></label>
</div>

And this is the list (removed real data for sharing):
<datalist id="companyDataList">
<option value="FO-000001 - Company Name 1">Company Name 1</option>
<option value="FO-000002 - Company Name 2">Company Name 2</option>
<option value="FO-000003 - Company Name 3">Company Name 3</option>
</datalist>

To reproduce the error, you need to use the Microsoft Edge with a Work Profile (as the Personal Profile and other browsers does not show the option to close the datalist) and a input tag type text using a datalist.
Once you click the input field, it will show the list and the option to close it.
If you click to close, you no longer can open it, even if you refresh the page.

It is most likely caused by the Edge auto-fill feature. You can try turning it off at edge://wallet/settings --> Save and fill basic info. Just toggle off this option and observe the behavior.

I did try it just now, toggled off, closed the browser, reopened it, but the issue is still there, on all pages where I closed the list before, it does not show again. I did then disable all flags in this setting pages and tried again, still no success.

@AndreDuarte Actually, using the code you provided and testing in Work profile, I got a different list (with no X) from your screenshot, which means I'm not able to reproduce this issue. The dropdown list from your screenshot belongs to the autofill feature of Microsoft Edge, so I suggest you turn off that. Now that it does not work for you, please consider providing another reproducible code example for us.
